# Why are Swifts access modifiers not private by default?

Tags: swift

I’m really wondering what’s the reasoning behind this. I find a lot of times that my code, for instance `IBActions` and `IBOutlets` are exposed where they shouldn’t be.

Comment: From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html), ___Swift reduces the need to specify explicit access control levels by providing default access levels for typical scenarios. Indeed, if you are writing a single-target app, you may not need to specify explicit access control levels at all.___ You might want to read the __Default Access Levels__ & __Access Levels for Single-Target Apps__ sections.

Comment: @nayem You shoould make that an answer.

Comment: So I guess it’s simplicity over safety?

Comment: Swift strongly favors safety over simplicity. `private` isn't about safety. It's about documenting intent and to a lesser extent about cross-framework performance (but mostly about intent IMO). There is nothing unsafe about calling an IBAction; it's just bad practice, and `private` doesn't even stop you from calling it since it's exposed to ObjC. The Swift team's intent was to keep simple programs simple and only force developers to learn and use new tools as their program benefits from them. But it rarely sacrifices safety to that goal.

Answer (score 0):

The default is to be `internal`, this means that you can access the identifier inside the same module, but not outside of it, this is very similar to how e.g. Java has `package private` access as it's default.

You can achieve good encapsulation with `internal`, but for even stricter encapsulation you can choose to use `private`.

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html